# RPA-Blueprism - Global Send Keys - Input text which has '(' is not working

Tags: blueprism, rpa

RPA-Blueprism - Global Send Keys - Input text which has '(' is not working. Only the text gets entered without brackets, please assist. 
Ex: 'Paste (Text)' is the text I want to send, however the text is sent to the field as 'Paste Text'

Comment: Why are using 'Global Send Key' option? Why can't you use 'Write' step? You can fill up a text field with use of 'Data Item' in wich you will have text you need to be writen.

Comment: I am using Data item it self to send the data from. This is under the AA mode, 'Write' step isn't working I have tried that as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Global Send Keys** internally uses **System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys** so characters like braces or parentheses must be escaped.

One way of doing it is using a **Calculation** stage with several **Replace** instructions, replacing the problematic characters with the escaped version.

For more information about **System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys** check the following MSDN link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Paste {(}Text{)}".

Comment: The brackets are not static, the text will be varying, so how to use {(}

Answer (score 0):

RPA-Blueprism - Global Send Keys for '(' then

```
{<SHIFT>9}</SHIFT> - Key down Shift button and press 9 releases the shift key, indirectly it does SHIFT + 9
```

Let's consider - If needed to write "("  manual key stroke would be SHIFT + 9

So if you have to send Global send key for the same, then use the above code
You can refer the blow link for more understanding

```
[https://seleniumsuite.blog/2017/11/07/global-send-keyglobal-send-key-events-in-blueprism/]
```

NOTE: Before sending any global send key event the application must be activated prior

Answer (score 0):

You can use "utility-string" VBO and call the "Escape special character string" for example if you pass `"paste(text)"` as input , it will give output as `"paste{(}text{)}"`. You can then use the output dataitem for global send keys action.